# ViewPager showing duplicate data

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am having the following problem,
first viewpager show wrongly the content of the second viewpager
when i slide to the second viewpager the content is the same,showing correctly the second viewpager
to fix this problem.I have to slide to the third so FragmentStatePagerAdapter can reload
then the content of the first viewpage is show correctly.

```
package com.example.android.effectivenavigation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    static int myViewPagerItem;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyPageAdapter mFragmentStatePagerAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        setContentView (R.layout.refuel_viewpager);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(mFragmentStatePagerAdapter);
    }
    public static class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            myViewPagerItem = i;
            return new ViewFragment();
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 10;
        }
    }
    public static class ViewFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view, container, false);
            TextView text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            text1.setText("Page: " + myViewPagerItem);
            return v;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you are no populating adapter that why myViewPagerItem show same value

Comment: it showing: page 2,2,3,4... and when i slide back 4,3,2,1 how i populate the adapter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyPageAdapter mFragmentStatePagerAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        setContentView (R.layout.refuel_viewpager);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(mFragmentStatePagerAdapter);
    }
    public  class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            return new ViewFragment(i);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 10;
        }
    }
    public  class ViewFragment extends Fragment {
        int pageno;
        public ViewFragment(int pageNo){
            this.pageno=pageNo;
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view, container, false);
            TextView text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            text1.setText("Page: " + pageno);
            return v;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: that solve it thank you very mutch, now i would apreciate to know why my method does not work!

Comment: Because you ware using static variable to show in fragments.When your say static its not a part of the class instance it creates only once and shared among the multiple fragment instance. And you ware changing it in getItem() method , as it is static was reflecting in all fragment instance and repeating.

Comment: i got my problem solved and got properly instructed, couldn't ask for more! thank you again!

Comment: This is an incorrect way to do it, please ensure you never have a fragment constructor that is non-empty, a better approach would be to send the page number as an argument in a bundle using setArguments!!!